# PHP typed properties bulk declare can't assign null to nullable field

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have stamp over counterintuitive bug/property.

```
class xxx{
    public ?int $a, $b;

    public function __construct($a, $b){
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}

new xxx(null, 10); //Working
new xxx(10, null); //Not working
```

Can someone explain to me why the second line is not working.

PHP version 7.4.2.

Comment: This is a known issue that is fixed in 7.4.3.

Comment: @NikiC You can put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NikiC pointed out in comment section: this is a known issue that is fixed in 7.4.3.